# Is there any hint as to which agent survived in Double Man?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-double-man

In [The Double Man](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061594/), a CIA agent, Dan Slater is investigating the death of his son, but he's captured and learns the Russians will replace him with an agent that looks exactly like him.

Near the end of the movie, his friend, Frank Wheatly, has both Dan and his clone cornered, and both convince him to shoot the other. We see a gun shot go off but not who was shot. In the end, Dan boards a train, but sees the Russian agent watching him.  Dan and his friend (another one sent to retrieve him), question his identity.

Is the ending left ambiguous or are there any subtle hints as to who survived?